# Why should a shared pointer be invalidated after modification?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

According to Herb Sutter's talk in [CppCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA&index=2&list=PLHTh1InhhwT75gykhs7pqcR_uSiG601oh), a `shared_ptr` should be invalidated after modification,

```
auto sv = make_shared<vector<int>>(100);
shared_ptr<vector<int>>* sv2 = &sv;
vector<int>* vec = &*sv;
int* ptr = &(*sv)[0];
*ptr = 1 ;

vec->push_back(2);        //A: modification
*ptr = 5;                 //Error: ptr was invalidated by "push_back" on line A

ptr = &(*sv)[0];
(*sv2).reset();            //B: modification
vec->push_back(6);         //Error: vec was invalidated by "reset" on line B
```

My compiler catches none of those errors. Anyway, we use smart pointers to prevent memory leakage. What's the reason to suppress modification of `shared_ptr`? To avoid surprises? If that is the case, can't we just declare it as `const`? On the other hand, if many operations on `vector`can't be applied because of the `share_ptr`, wouldn't it be inconvenient?

---

After reading the comments, now I start to understand what it really does here. The modification of the `shared_ptr` invalidates other raw pointers pointing to it.

As dyp points out in the comment, `push_back` might reallocate, which might invalidate `ptr`. If it doesn't reallocate, should `ptr` still be valid? If it does reallocate, wouldn't it be simpler and more constructive if the compiler just carries all its buddies to the new territory, say, assigns those raw pointers with the new address?

Comment: To be clear, the shared pointer isn't invalidated; he's saying that other, non-managed pointers to the same resource are invalidated. I can't answer that either though.

Comment: Can you point out where in the video he is saying this?

Comment: `vec->push_back` might reallocate, in which case pointers into the old allocation become invalid. This is the case for `ptr` in example A. Similarly, if you reset a `shared_ptr` and it's the only owner of the vector, then that vector will be destroyed and pointers to (and into) that vector become invalid. That's the case for `vec` in example B.

Comment: Reducing the code even more, you could simply demonstrate the dangling pointer using a vector with automatic storage. I don't understand what's surprising here.

Comment: vec is a raw pointer, which becomes dangled after sv2 is reset. What @UlrichEckhardt said. Other than (*sv2).reset(), you did not actually modify the shared_ptr, all the coded did was modifying the raw pointer. As soon as the sv shared_ptr was reset by (*sv2).reset(), the raw pointers ptr and vec become dangling pointers, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Why is it not valid?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: What does it do?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Oh, that's a pointer-to-a-shared_ptr. Okay. This code is really confusing....

Comment: I've watched the talk and nowhere does Herb Sutter claim that you should invalidate the shared pointers. What exactly makes you think he does? And at what time of the video does it happen? As far as I see it, the point of that part of the talk is how a compiler could in theory catch such errors because code-analysis tools can catch them; and perhaps that the presence of smart pointers does not magically eliminate all errors.

Comment: Really confusing indeed, and all that just say something everybody already knows (or should): pointer aliasing should be done very carefully.

Comment: @AndyG code is around 52' in the talk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the greater context of things, Herb was advertising for the [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) at CPPCon 2015 (He wasn't the only one).

The point he was trying to make was that there exists code that is perfectly legal according to the standard, but with static analysis we can tell it is problematic.

In the example given here, we have a `shared_ptr` to a `vector`, and then a raw pointer to that pointer, and then a raw pointer to the vector held by the shared pointer, and even a raw pointer to an element held within the vector held within the shared pointer.

And then he did a bunch of things that would result in undefined behavior. The calls were perfectly legal (call reset on a `shared_ptr` and then attempt to perform an operation on a `vector`) however in the greater context of things, he was arguing that a compiler *should* be able to tell you (via static analysis) that you did a Bad Thing.

So in the video you see him do these bad things that no modern compiler would catch, and then demonstrate how a compiler (In this case Visual Studio 2015) imbued with the GSL *will* catch them.

The talk was equally political as it was informative. Visual Studio was used likely because Herb himself is a Microsoft employee.This isn't necessarily a bad thing; it's widely accepted that Visual Studio is a great IDE, and I think the message to take away is that Microsoft is indeed committed to C++, despite a lot of moves in recent years that demonstrated perhaps a higher commitment to C#, which left C++ developers feeling like second class citizens.